# How to retrieve all subfolders and files using BitBucket REST?

Tags: powershell, bitbucket-api

I have powershell script which retrieves file from **"Packages"** folder.
It works correct.

```
$DOWNLOAD_PATH = "C:\bitbucket\"

$uri = "https://bitbucket.org.dev/projects/TEST/repos/fa/browse/Packages/test1.txt"
$API_KEY="ZTUxhso"
Invoke-WebRequest -Headers @{Authorization=$("Basic {0}" -f $API_KEY)} -Uri $uri  -OutFile $DOWNLOAD_PATH\test1.txt
```

But Packages folder contains more files and subfolders which also contain different set of files. 
How can I retrieve them all in my script and put them on my system using the REST??? I searched on the google but could not find it :-(

Thank you in advance!